# How does the Percent_Lifetime_Remaining SMART attribute get calculated on a Crucial MX500 disk?

Tags: zfs, ssd, smart

I have a home lab grade server that I put 4x Crucial MX500 disks into a couple months ago.  One of the disks (they're all similar) has the following SMART details:

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-05-07 r4318 [x86_64-linux-3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Crucial/Micron BX/MX1/2/3/500, M5/600, 1100 SSDs
Device Model:     CT500MX500SSD1
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 00a075 1e1e22806
Firmware Version: M3CR023
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA >3.2 (0x1ff), 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Fri Aug  9 17:29:43 2019 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x80) Offline data collection activity
                                        was never started.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:                (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  30) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x0031) SCT Status supported.
                                        SCT Feature Control supported.
                                        SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  5 Reallocate_NAND_Blk_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       554
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       35
171 Program_Fail_Count      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
172 Erase_Fail_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
173 Ave_Block-Erase_Count   0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       127
174 Unexpect_Power_Loss_Ct  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       9
180 Unused_Reserve_NAND_Blk 0x0033   000   000   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       43
183 SATA_Interfac_Downshift 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 Error_Correction_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   064   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       36 (Min/Max 0/54)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
202 Percent_Lifetime_Remain 0x0030   092   092   001    Old_age   Offline      -       8
206 Write_Error_Rate        0x000e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
210 Success_RAIN_Recov_Cnt  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
246 Total_Host_Sector_Write 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       7227541253
247 Host_Program_Page_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       128825080
248 FTL_Program_Page_Count  0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1974407892
```

I'm trying to figure out how attribute `202` is calculated because it seems to be dropping pretty fast.  I have ZFS on the machine and, with 41 days of uptime, `zpool iostat -v` it shows:

```
                                capacity     operations     bandwidth
pool                                 alloc   free   read  write   read  write
-----------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
neo                                  1.10T   727G    123    174  4.84M  2.27M
  raidz1                             1.10T   727G    123    174  4.84M  2.27M
    ata-CT500MX500SSD1_1XXXXXXXXXXX      -      -     31     44  1.23M   597K
    ata-CT500MX500SSD1_1XXXXXXXXXXX      -      -     30     42  1.19M   567K
    ata-CT500MX500SSD1_1XXXXXXXXXXX      -      -     31     44  1.23M   597K
    ata-CT500MX500SSD1_1XXXXXXXXXXX      -      -     30     42  1.19M   567K
-----------------------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
```

As far as I understand that, it's less than 1MB/s per disk being written.  Roughly estimating the amount of data written I get 1MB/s = 86GB per day or 2.5TB per month.  The rated 180TBW / 2.5TB per month is roughly 72 months or 6 years.  However, I've gone through 8% in about 2.5 months.

I'd like to know how attribute `202` is calculated so I can do it by hand and start trying to figure out if I have some type of write amplification issue.  I'm sort of hesitant to trust the SMART stats because they show 23 days of PoH even though the system has 41 days of uptime and the particular model of disk also has a notorious `CurrentPendingSector` issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Traditionally, the "percent lifetime remaining" is the average erase count versus the actual flash "rated endurance".  This implies that the MX500 has 1500 endurance flash, which is believable for TLC 3D flash.

The ZFS /z1 layout, to a consumer SSD, pushes a lot of drive sync commands.  This really increases the write amplification of the individual drives.  I have tested larger arrays (by drive count) and have seen > 20X amplification just at the ZFS level before the drives internal logic (this was a zvol 100% random 4K write workload, so worst case).

Your array is only 2.3X worse than your own calculations (8% after 2.5 month is 31 months versus your hoped 72 months).  This is easily explained by the ZFS write behavior.  In other words, you are getting what is expected from a consumer drive with ZFS in /z1.

Non consumer drives, even when built with the same flash have power-fail hardware that lets syncs happen without actually syncing the FTL layout every time.  This lowers wear a lot and makes ZFS much more "survivable", while still slow compared to other file systems.

Comment: What about mirrors?  I have 2x MX500 that have been up for a year ish in a mirror, with around 1M/s writes, and SMART is reporting them as worn out completely.  There's NO WAY I've written enough to these drives to account for that, unless there's a firmware bug

Answer (score -1):

Don't worry!! I lost sleep today worried about the same problem!  8 in 202 parameter is a USE!

https://www.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/ssds-and-smart-data

Attribute 202: Percentage Lifetime Used

This attribute is exactly as its name implies. It is a measure of how much of the drive’s projected lifetime has been used at any point in time. When the SSD is brand new, Attribute 202 will report “0”, and when its specified lifetime has been reached, it will show “100,” reporting that 100 percent of the lifetime has been used.

However, it’s important to realize what it means to reach 100 percent of projected lifetime – it does not mean that the drive is going to fail when that counter rolls over to 101 percent, only that your SSD may need to be replaced soon.

Comment: OP clearly understands what that attribute means and the other answer has already explained how it's calculated.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser. This is not a discussion forum. Here we do questions and answers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure why this answer is being downvoted- it's a useful heads-up that it doesn't actually mean "remain[ing]" and answers OP's question about how it's calculated with a source; upvoted as it was clear and helpful to me :)